# Disagreement between R functions isSymmetric() and is.positive.semi.definite()

Tags: r, debugging, linear-algebra

I have a custom function that generates a positive semidefinite matrix. However, when I test whether it is PSD using `is.positive.semi.definite()`, I get an error that says its not symmetric despite `isSymmetric()` being TRUE.

**Anyone know whats going on? Why is matrix failing to be PSD?**

```r
#Custom Function that finds Positive SemiDefinite Matrix:
find_closest_PDM <- function(mat) {
  updated_mat <- mat
  all_positive = FALSE
  while (!all_positive) {
    evalues <- eigen(updated_mat)$values
    evectors <- eigen(updated_mat)$vectors
    if (sum(evalues < 0) > 0) {
      evalues <- pmax(evalues,0)
      updated_mat = evectors %*% diag(evalues) %*%  solve(evectors)
      diag(updated_mat) <- 1
      
    } else if (!isSymmetric(updated_mat)) {
      updated_mat <- forceSymmetric(updated_mat)
      
    } else {
      all_positive = TRUE
    }
  }
  updated_mat
}

#testing
A <- matrix(c(1, -0.81, 0.9, -0.81, 1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 1), nrow = 3)
isSymmetric(A)
matrixcalc::is.positive.semi.definite(A)

test1 <- find_closest_PDM(mat = A)
isSymmetric(test1)
matrixcalc::is.positive.semi.definite(test1)


#My results LOOKS to be exactly correct when compared to another method:
test1
sfsmisc::nearcor(A)$cor
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where you found the `is.positive.semi.definite()` function, but there's a function with that name in the `matrixcalc` package.  It tests for exact symmetry, whereas `isSymmetric()` tests using a default tolerance of `100 * .Machine$double.eps`.

You might get exact symmetry using `(updated_mat + t(updated_mat))/2` in your function, though there might be cases where that will just get very close, since order of addition sometimes makes a difference in computer arithmetic.  I don't think it should in this case, though.  (That might be what `forceSymmetric` does, but it's hard to see the internals of `Matrix` functions.)